# GAS Function doGet does not trigger on Page embed when embedded on a new page (http mixed content)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-sites, mixed-content

I've created the below GAS code for my company's internal Google Sites intranet. It pulls the time and the logged-in user and posts the page they have viewed so we can confirm our employees are using the intranet tools and what information is most valuable to them. As we add new content to the intranet, I duplicate this script and embed it into the new Google sites page using the Insert >> Google Apps Script prompt. And yes, I ensure that the Admin SDK and Google Sheets services are enabled. I can even run the doGet function from within the Apps-Script environment, and everything works like a charm.

For a reason I cannot figure out, this script does not work when embedding into new pages. I've tried the following steps:

1) Confirm the script is currently working on a page [successful]

2) Create a new Google Announcement Page

3) Embed the exact script from step 1 into the new Google Page

4) Refresh the new page and check if the script populated the log sheet [FAILED]

Here is my code below:

```html
/*
This Script Needs the following Advanced Services to function:

  Admin Directory
  
  This Script Could be used with the following library, but is not required:

  BetterLog: MYB7yzedMbnJaMKECt6Sm7FLDhaBgl_dE

  
*/ 

//PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperties({'LogSheet':'1hw3f5ywdbF6JuRd1lPzrCthNaMb5InHl9VBP-xxxxxx', 'ErrSheet': '1_PHc1EU0JYLJirMceAP_enktaP3HJmGHS407Oxxxxx'});

try{
//-------------------------------------------------
  
var ACTIVE = true;
 
  
var PAGE = 'Name of the Page to Track';
var TYPE = 'Article';
var GROUP = 'Department Name';
var URL = 'https://sites.google.com/a/Intranet/URL for the Article';
//--------------------------------------------------  

if(ACTIVE){ 
var errorTemplate = 'Analytics_Error_Log_started_';
var logTemplate = 'Analytics_Log_started_'
var now = new Date();
var date = Utilities.formatDate(now, 'CST', 'MM/dd/YYYY');
var time = Utilities.formatDate(now, 'CST', 'hh:mm:ss a');
var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
var scriptStore = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperties();
var errorFolder = '0B6w6hIuCv6BtdHl1S09kbxxxx';
var logFolder = '0B6w6hIuCv6BtWldmYjdEbxxxxx';
var logSheet = getSheet('LogSheet', logTemplate, logFolder);
var errSheet = getSheet('ErrSheet', errorTemplate, errorFolder);
var scriptStore = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperties();
var errSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptStore.ErrSheet).getSheets()[0];
var logSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptStore.LogSheet).getSheets()[0];
   }
 }
catch(e){Logger.log('Compiler Error in File TK-'+PAGE+': '+e);}
  
function doGet(){
     
     try{if(ACTIVE){
              logSheet.appendRow([date, time, user.name.givenName, user.name.familyName, PAGE, TYPE, GROUP, user.primaryEmail, URL]);
     }}
  
     catch(e) {report(e);}
}

function report(e){
Logger.log(date+' '+time+' '+user.primaryEmail+' at '+PAGE+' : '+e);
errSheet.appendRow([date, time, user.primaryEmail, PAGE, e]);

  
}

function getSheet(scriptStoreVal,template, folderId){
  var sheetId = scriptStore[scriptStoreVal];
  try{var book = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);}
  catch(e){var sheetId = generateSheet(template+date, folderId);}
  
  var book = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
  var sheets = book.getSheets();  
  var sheet = sheets[0];
  
  if(sheet.getLastRow() >= 50000){
    var fileList = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();
    var found = false;
    while(fileList.hasNext())
    { 
      var testFile = fileList.next().getId();
      if (SpreadsheetApp.openById(testFile).getSheets()[0].getLastRow() < 50000)
      { 
        var book = SpreadsheetApp.openById(testFile)
        var sheet = book.getSheets()[0];
        var sheetId = testFile;
        var found = true;}
    }
    
    if(!found)
    {
      var sheetId = generateSheet(template+date, folderId);
      var book = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
      var sheets = book.getSheets();
      var sheet = sheets[0];
    }
    
    for (var s = 1; s < book.getNumSheets(); s++)
    {
      book.deleteSheet(sheets[s]);
    }
  }
  if(book.getName().indexOf('Er') > -1)
     {
       try{sheet.deleteColumns(4,22); sheet.appendRow(['Error Message: Press Ctrl Down to scroll to end. 50K Max'])}
      catch(e){/*Sheet does not have 26 columns. We are set*/}
    }
  else
     {
       try{sheet.deleteColumns(8, 17); sheet.appendRow(['Date', 'Time', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Page', 'Type', 'Group','Email', 'URL']);}
       catch(e){/*Sheet does not have 26 columns. We are set*/}
    }
  
     var patch = {}; patch[scriptStoreVal] = sheetId;
     PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperties(patch);
  
  return sheet;
}


function generateSheet(sheetName, folderId)
{
  var origId = SpreadsheetApp.create(sheetName).getId();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(origId);
  var start = file.getParents().next();
  DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).addFile(file);
  start.removeFile(file);
  return origId;
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out why this function, which still works on my previous pages, does not work on my new pages?

Thanks,
   Nathaniel

UPDATE: Per suggestion from noogui, I pulled up the Chrome debug console and noticed the page was flagging the apps script insertion as a mixed request over http. Here is the HTML of the page currently:

```html
<div>


<div></div>
<br>
</div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div><img src="https://www.google.com/chart?chc=sites&amp;cht=d&amp;chdp=sites&amp;chl=%5B%5BGoogle+Apps+Script'%3D20'f%5Cv'a%5C%3D0'10'%3D499'0'dim'%5Cbox1'b%5CF6F6F6'fC%5CF6F6F6'eC%5C0'sk'%5C%5B%22Apps+Script+Gadget%22'%5D'a%5CV%5C%3D12'f%5C%5DV%5Cta%5C%3D10'%3D0'%3D500'%3D297'dim'%5C%3D10'%3D13'%3D500'%3D297'vdim'%5Cbox1'b%5Cva%5CF6F6F6'fC%5CC8C8C8'eC%5C'a%5C%5Do%5CLauto'f%5C&amp;sig=zdJ4UDJFmGvXXHTFJf3RLHWWKks" data-props="align:left;showBorder:false;showBorderTitle:false;borderTitle:Apps Script Gadget;height:200" id="388247003045773" data-type="maestro" class="sites-placeholder-maestro" data-origsrc="https://script.google.com/a/intranet/macros/s/AKfycbxIpjE0HKKYBWpB16fB3D7BPeLtP-Y-FXLnWk3l-w853qSloes/exec" width="500" height="300" style="display: block; text-align: left;"></div>
<br>
```

As you can see, the image placeholder AND the script itself are referenced via HTTPS, so what gives? I don't understand why it would flag a mixed http error.

Comment: What does your error log say?

Comment: In Chrome developer console: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://sites.google.com/a/intranet/test/test3' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://sites.google.com/a/intranet/sites/system/errors/WebspaceNotFound?path=%2Fmacros%2Fs%2FAKfycbwKAHCJgn9yeJ2G0ZxOlXwcClDV9hFY2RSHOZWU6gUUdddosv4P%2Fexec'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS. Note that this does not show when I run the SAME script on the page that I first used it on, which works fine. I think I am attaching it correctly, so I don't understand why it doesn't work now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is helpful, but for our google sites intranet we use Google analytics. It takes care of everything and even has AI now to help with analysing the data. Under the Manage Site Settings there is a place to insert the analytics key. It is totally free and dynamic, so any new pages/articles you add are automatically tracked.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Supertopoz, but we are not using this to analyze public site visits, but to record individual employees when they visit a page. Google Analytics does not allow that level of Granularity due to privacy concerns, so we can't use it.